# How to access AWS resources created by secondary root account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-organizations

**Background:** A year and a half ago my company purchased a web development project from a software company. Now I try to access the recourses in the AWS console, but I can't see any of the created and running resources. E.g. I see [no active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Rvo.png) EC2's using the management account. I only see that the resources are being billed from the [cost management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnJAV.png), including EC2.

I created an AWS account (root user) and added the software company's personnel as parallel root users ([AWS oranization's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWQXj.png), where my account is the management account). I don't have access to the other created root accounts.

**Question:** How can I access the resources created by other accounts in the organization? I would like to change the git repo where EC2 is pulling the code it runs etc.

I am familiar with Azure, but AWS has always been very unfamiliar to me.

I tried to familiarize myself with the access policies (IAM) of AWS as well as search for best practices on how this is done. However, I found that creating parallel root users is not definitely the best practice. Thus I did not find any resolution to the initial problem.

I tried to use AWS Resource Manager, to find the resources, but it does not seem to help as the resources created won't show up in my management account.

I tried to use AWS Resource Explorer, to find the resources, but it did not show the active resources either.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no access to the account included in your organization and from where the billings are generated, I guess that the only way is to open a support ticket and explain your problem.

The right way was to grant a cross-account access from you secondary account to the management Organization account, as explained in [Accessing and administering the member accounts in your organization - AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html).

Comment: Hi Filippo and thanks for your advice! I'll contact support and see where it takes me as the person with access to the accounts already works in another organization.